# Plot implicit equation in sub-quadratic time complexity

Tags: algorithms, graphing-functions, computational-complexity

It is fairly straightforward to plot an explicit equation such as $y=x^3+3x^2+2x+5$ in linear time, because you can just iterate through all $x$ in your graphing space and use the equation to calculate $y$ for every $x$.

However, if we need to plot an arbitrary implicit equation, such as $y^2+y+x^3+3x^2+5=0$, past questions seem to suggest that it can only be plotted in quadratic time, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891396/why-does-this-algorithm-to-plot-implicit-equations-work).

My question: Is there any sub-quadratic algorithm to plot an arbitrary implicit equation? (Or do I need to do algebraic manipulation, which will make the use of such a sub-quadratic plotting algorithm very limited?)

This question is completely theoretical, and I'm just wondering if an algorithm exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have specific knowledge about the behavior of the function, the answer is negative.

[Even for the 1D case, it is an oversimplification to say that linear time is enough. By sampling at discrete points, you can always miss important features such as asymptotes.]

For a similar reason, in 2D you cannot drop a part of the domain as you can't predict what happens there. And an implicit equation can very well "fill" the whole domain.

Think of

$$2\sin100x\cdot\sin100y=1$$